# How to check type of Exception occured in java and call another method accordingly?

Tags: java, exception

I have

```
public static void main(String[] args){
String text = parseXml(XmlText); // Exception occurs here in called method.
}
```

I want to check the type of exception occurred while parsing xml and call another method accordingly like this.

```
if(thisException){
   String text = anotherMethod(xmlText);
}
```

How can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a try catch for this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        String text = parseXml(XmlText);
        // do something
    } 
    catch ([THE EXCEPTION TYPE] ex){
         String text = anotherMethod(xmlText);
         // do something else
    }
}
```

Your application will still crash if the exception is not handled in your catch. You can also catch different types of exceptions and handle them accordingly by adding another catch-clause. E.g.

```
catch (EXCEPTION1 EX) {
    // ...
}
catch (EXCEPTION2 EX) {
    // ...
}
```